# on_member_ban() and on_member_remove() in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I have a bot with two events: `on_member_ban()` and `on_member_remove()`. Whenever a user is banned, it calls both functions but I only want it to call `on_member_ban()`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check to the `on_member_remove` that returns if the user was banned:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    try:
        await member.guild.fetch_ban(member)
        return
    except discord.NotFound:
        # Your logic here
```